# Waiting for location change to ends

Tags: android, service, gps

I have a service that sends data for server periodically, and the longitude and the latitude are from the data to be sent.
The problem is the async task always starts its execution before the registerLocationUpdates() ends, please help me in solving it, the only thing i want is ro guarantee that the PostQos task won't be executed until the register location updates ends.

```
public class QosTestsService extends Service {

private Handler handler;
SharedPreferences mshared;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
double longitude = 0.0, latitude = 0.0;
String provider;
boolean waitingForLocationUpdate = true;

private boolean firstTime = true, running = true;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, " MyService Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    int delay = 5000; //milliseconds
    mshared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());


    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, MyApplication.routineSchedule.getFrequency() * 60 * 1000);
            if (MyApplication.routineSchedule.getEnabled().equals("true")){

                registerLocationUpdates(); 
                new PostQosTest(getApplicationContext(), true).execute();
            } 
        }
    }, delay);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void registerLocationUpdates() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Cant get a hold of provider
    if (provider == null) {
        return;
    }

    locationListener = new MyLocationListener();


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    // connect to the GPS location service
    Location oldLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (oldLocation != null) {
        waitingForLocationUpdate = false;
    }
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("hello im here", "the value are " + latitude + " "
                + longitude);// , msg)
        // Log.v(TAG, "IN ON LOCATION CHANGE");

        if (waitingForLocationUpdate) {
            // getNearbyStores();
            waitingForLocationUpdate = false;
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // Log.v(TAG, "Status changed: " + s);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "PROVIDER DISABLED: " + s);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        // Log.e(TAG, "PROVIDER DISABLED: " + s);
    }
}



private class PostQosTest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String ipAddress, res;
    Profile profile;
    Context context;
    String carrierName;
    QosTest qosTest;
    boolean isSignalStrength;
    String testDate;

    public PostQosTest(Context context, boolean isSignalStrength){

        this.context = context;
        this.isSignalStrength = isSignalStrength;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        try {
            testDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            InetAddress ip = Actions.GetIp();
            ipAddress = ip.toString();

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        TCTDbAdapter sour = new TCTDbAdapter(context);
        sour.open();
        ArrayList<Profile> arr = sour.getAllProfiles();
        profile = arr.get(0);
        sour.close();

        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        carrierName = manager.getSimOperatorName();

        qosTest = new QosTest();

        qosTest.setId(0);

        try {
            qosTest.setUserId(profile.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setUserId("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setDeviceId(String.valueOf(mshared.getInt(getString(R.string.device_id), 0)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setDeviceId("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setDeviceModel(Actions.getDeviceName());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            qosTest.setDeviceModel("");
        }

        qosTest.setDeviceType("1");

        try {
            qosTest.setServiceProvider(carrierName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setServiceProvider("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setIp(ipAddress.substring(1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setIp("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setLocationIPAddress(MyApplication.ip);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setLocationIPAddress("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setLocationX(Double.toString(longitude));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setLocationX("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setLocationY(Double.toString(latitude));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setLocationY("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setTimeStamp("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setTimeStamp("");
        }

        qosTest.setTestType(isSignalStrength ? MyApplication.SIGNAL_STRENGTH_TEST : MyApplication.CALL_DISCONNECTION_TEST);

        qosTest.setCallDisconnectionReason("");

        try {
            qosTest.setTestDateTime(testDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setTestDateTime(testDate);
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setIsIncident("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setIsIncident("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setSignalStrength("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setSignalStrength("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setConnectionType(NetworkUtil.getNetworkClass(context));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setConnectionType(NetworkUtil.getNetworkClass(context));
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setCallDuration("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setCallDuration("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setTestTriggerType("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setTestTriggerType("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setTriggerStartDate("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setTriggerStartDate("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setValidationEndDate("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setValidationEndDate("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setResultId("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setResultId("");
        }

        try {
            qosTest.setStatusId("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            qosTest.setStatusId("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... a) {
        // URLEncoder.encode(searchText, "utf-8");
        String url = ****;
        try {
            url = url
                    + "UserId="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(profile.getId(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "mobileNumber="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(profile.getnum(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "ServiceProvider="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getServiceProvider(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "ipAddress="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getIp(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "LocationIPAddress="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getLocationIPAddress(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "DeviceId="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(qosTest.getDeviceId()), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "DeviceModel="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getDeviceModel(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "DeviceType="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getDeviceType(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "LocationX="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getLocationX(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "LocationY="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getLocationY(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "TestTypeId="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getTestType(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "CallDisconnectionReason="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getCallDisconnectionReason(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "TestDate="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getTestDateTime(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "IsIncident="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getIsIncident(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "SignalStrength="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getSignalStrength(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "ConnectionType="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getConnectionType(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "CallDuration="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getCallDuration(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "TestTriggerTypeId="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getTestTriggerType(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "TriggerStartDate="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getTriggerStartDate(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "ValidationEndDate="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getValidationEndDate(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "ResultId="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getResultId(), "utf-8")
                    + "&"
                    + "StatusId="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(qosTest.getStatusId(), "utf-8");



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

...
        return "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I just moved the execution code to the last line in the on location changed function.